# Hibernate update is sometimes not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a requirement where I am updating rows according to uuid's where one uuid may be associated to more than one rows.

Here's the scenario:
4a90558c-4a5b-4af7-8c68-60ff81f74ef3 is my uuid and it exists in 8 columns in my DB.

and my java code is as follows:

```
    try{
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        tx = session.getTransaction();
        criteria = session.createCriteria(Archive.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("bagUuid",  "4a90558c-4a5b-4af7-8c68-60ff81f74ef3"));
        ScrollableResults items = criteria.scroll();

         while ( items.next() ) {
             Archive archive = (Archive)items.get(0);
             archive.setDecision(1);
             archive.setOperatorAssigned("test");
             session.saveOrUpdate(archive);
             session.flush();
             session.clear();
         }
         tx.commit();
        LOGGER.info("Archive Record is updated: "+archive.getFilePath());
    }catch(Exception e){
        recordUpdated = false;
        tx.rollback();
        LOGGER.error("Archive Record failed to update due to exception in updateArchiveRecord method: "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Here sometimes all records associated to UUID is updating but sometimes failing. 
I think it may be a issue with the Hibernate API.
Does anybody else has faced the same issue.

Comment: If somebody told you that something failed, what would be your next question? Most probably it would be: In which way did it fail? Did it ignore the updates or threw an exception? In case it is an exception, what would you ask next? Probably: Which exception?

Comment: use an `e.printStackTrace();` in catch

Comment: No exceptions at all. sometimes it updates 8, sometimes 2 and sometimes 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line looks suspicious:

```
Archive archive = (Archive)items.get(0);
```

It means thart regardless of the number of items in the ScrollableResults, you will be updating only the first Archive object. If I understood what you are trying to do correctly, it should be a current record:

```
Archive archive = (Archive)items.get();
```

Also, I'd move out/delete session.flush() and session.clear(). The final code would look like this:

```
try{
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    tx = session.getTransaction();
    criteria = session.createCriteria(Archive.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("bagUuid",  "4a90558c-4a5b-4af7-8c68-60ff81f74ef3"));
    ScrollableResults items = criteria.scroll();

     while ( items.next() ) {
         Archive archive = (Archive)items.get();
         archive.setDecision(1);
         archive.setOperatorAssigned("test");
         session.saveOrUpdate(archive);
     }
     tx.commit();
     session.close();
    LOGGER.info("Archive Record is updated: "+archive.getFilePath());
}catch(Exception e){
    recordUpdated = false;
    tx.rollback();
    LOGGER.error("Archive Record failed to update due to exception in updateArchiveRecord method: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Slava Imeshev